# How do I reverse the order of a single column

Tags: command-line

Given that I have a table of text in columns, how can I reverse the order of the 3rd column? That is:

```
111a 2a   333a
11b  222b 33b
1c   22c  3c
```

How can I convert that into this?

```
111a 2a   3c
11b  222b 33b
1c   22c  333a
```

(Actual data considerably longer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reverse the third column, you could use blockwise Visual mode to select and delete the first two columns, use the command `:sort!` to reverse the remaining text (third column), and then paste the first two columns back where they were. Here are the keystrokes:

```
gg<C-v>Gwwhx:sort!<CR>P
```

Note that the command `:sort!` is not actually reversing the text - it's putting the text in reverse sorted order. To actually reverse the text you could use the command `:g/^/exe 'm .-' . line('.')`.

As an alternative, the following mapping will reverse the visually selected column - you can use `<C-v>${up/down motion(s)}` or `:set virtualedit=all` to select the last column.

```
xnoremap <silent> \r y:<C-u>call setreg('"', reverse(getreg('"', 1, 1)), getregtype('"'))<CR>gvp
```

This mapping yanks the selected text into the default register, reverses the contents of the default register, reselects the previously selected region, and then pastes the contents of the default register over the selected region.

Comment: `:sort!` would be *sorted* reversed order, I think OP just wants reversed order, as in the `reverse()` code you have shown.

Comment: There is an issue with an empty line (file terminated with \n) at BOF. (Resolved by deleting or ignoring it.) Otherwise, this works a treat! Thanks!